# Absolute value question

Tags: absolute-value

Is it true that:$$\left|\,a-b+c-c\,\right|=\left|\,(c-a)+(c-b)\,\right|,$$ or, alternatively,
$$\left|\,a-b+c-c\,\right| = \left|\,(a-c)+(c-b)\, \right|?$$

Why is this the case?

Comment: Simplify the expression. What is $c-c$?

Comment: The first is not correct. While considering a modulus you can always multiply what's inside with a root of unity (for example $-1,1$ and so on) and the result does not change, yet you cannot swap the signs of only half of the terms, since this would, generally speaking, change the value/result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's false. Example: $a = b = 1; c = 2$> left hand side is |a-b+c-c| = 0; right hand side is $|(2-1) + (2-1)| = |2| = 2$.

The second claim is correct, because $a - b + c - c = (a-c) + (b-c)$ by commutative and distributive properties, and since they are equal, their absolute values are equal as well.

Answer (score 1):

$|a-b+c-c| \neq |(c-a)+(c-b)|$. As a counterexample, let $a=0, b=10, c=5$.

---

$|a-b+c-c| = |a+(-b)+c+(-c)| = |(a+(-c))+(c+(-b))| = |(a-c)+(c-b)|$

Answer (score 0):

Since we have

a - b + c - c = a - b

We get a counterexample for the first equation with

a = b , $a\ne c$

The second equation is trivially right.